# jQuery и переключение без перезагрузки

Tags: jquery

Приветствую! У меня такая проблема: пытаюсь реализовать переключение по ссылкам без перезагрузки страницы, а именно отправляя $.post и меняя содержимое #content-блока. При клике на ссылку вне блока #content все работает, но когда нажимаешь ссылку внутри этого блока - страница открывается с перезагрузкой.
Вот сам скрипт, в php просто отправляется скрипт с подменой блока, а в js:

```
$('a').click(function(){
var href = $(this).attr('href');
cl(href);
return false;
});
function cl(href) {
$.post(href,{act: 'load'},function (result) {eval(result);});
return false;
}
```

Comment: `eval(result)` - это просто ужас! и 

    cl(href);
    return false;

можна заменить на:

    return cl(href);

или `$.post(...)` на `return $.ajax(...)`

Comment: "eval(result)" - здесь я код обрезал, там в продолжении это используется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто вы обновляете DOM и новые ссылки не знают, что не нужно перегружать страницу.

Попробуйте вместо

```
$('a').click(function(){...})
```

использовать

```
$('a').live('click', function(){...})
```

live привязывает событие не только ко всем текущим элементам DOM, но и к новым, динамически созданным

Comment: сколько можно использовать live?